Cannot Generate a PDF from Google Script
I followed a Youtube tutorial to create a google script that would produce a pdf from google sheets. I was able to recreate what I saw in the video and generated a pdf. When it came time to put in my specific specs, the PDF would not generate for me. I've tried troubleshooting but I'm too much of a newbie to figure it out.
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  createPDF(info);

}


function createPDF(info){

   const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1TzHSBQVLBTFRMJLNc3y_ZfFSJCN8YN-u");
   const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1dAdxsFtuowCSQgHOrU6GrkQvUH86YG_E");
   const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1lC50FzTsvwvO-5981OCob4-ideeqKN91VzC1WMO7dRw");

   const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
   const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
   const body = openDoc.getBody();

   body.replaceText("{{name}}", info['Employee name'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{restaurant}}", info['Restaurant where employee works'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{position}}", info['Employees position'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{race}}", info['What is the employees race'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{origin}}", info['What is the employees national orgin'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{age}}", info['What is the employees exact age'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{gender}}", info['What is the employees gender'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{orientation}}", info['What is the employees sexual orientation if   known'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{health}}", info['Has the employee ever disclosed that they have any   ongoing health issues to anyone in management'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{leave}}", info['Has the employee recently taken a leave'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{pregnant}}", info['Is the employee pregnant or was the employee   recently pregnant'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{religion}}", info['Has the employee ever requested any religious accommodations'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{complaint}}", info['Has the employee ever raised a complaint of harassment, discrimination, or sexual harassment to anyone in management'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{information}}", info['Please provide any other relevant information about the employee'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{reason}}", info['Reason for termination request'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{answer}}", info['Has the employee ever been issued any written   disciplinary action form? If yes, please provide copies of all disciplinary warnings with this request'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{{manager}}", info['Name of manager completing this form'][0]);
   openDoc.saveAndClose();

   const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
   const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Employee name'][0] + " "+       info['Restaurant where employee works'][0]);
   tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
   }

}


Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question doesn't include enough details. Apparently, this script is intended to be called by the form submit trigger for a spreadsheet, but this is not mentioned in the question. Also, the question doesn't mention what changes you made to the code and doesn't include details about how the script is run / tested. Ref. [mcve]. You might have to start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting

What are the particular specs you are having trouble with?

the debug says e: undefined, info: undefined, and pdfFile: undefined

I linked the google form to the spreadsheet, the spreadsheet to google script and then I set a trigger to run the script to afterFormSubmit. When I fill out the form it shows up in the spreadsheet but the PDF isn't produced.

Comments are not intended to share relevant details about the question. Please [edit] the question to add the relevant to the question body.

It may not be your problem because I looked closely at the event object and I found an extra space that should not have been in there on one of my return values.  So I suspect google may be having a problem on some form submissions.
My code is very similar to yours but not exactly because I am using a form that I have had for a long time
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder1id);
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder2id);
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.testdocid);
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{{COL1}}", e.namedValues["1. Question"][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{COL2}}", e.namedValues["2. Question "][0]);//I should not have had to put this space at the end of "2. Question"
  body.replaceText("{{COL3}}", e.namedValues["3. Question"][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{COL4}}", e.namedValues["4. Question"][0]);
  body.replaceText("{{COL5}}", e.namedValues["5. Question"][0]);
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(e.namedValues["6. Question"]);
}

Execution Log:
{"authMode":"FULL","namedValues":{"2. Question ":["two"],"Score":[""],"6. Question":["six"],"5. Question":["five"],"4. Question":["four"],"":["","","",""],"3. Question":["three"],"Email Address":[""],"Timestamp":["7/1/2024 18:18:54"],"1. Question":["one"]},"range":{"columnEnd":9,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":47,"rowStart":47},"source":{},"triggerUid":"","values":["7/1/2024 18:18:54","one","two","three","four","five","six","","","","","",""]}

The space after "2. Question " should not be there because it's not in the form so check your execution log carefully; maybe you are having the same sort or problem.
But once I fixed the issue by adding the extra space I was able to generate pdfs  just fine. You could try using e.values instead and get them by index.

Thanks for the response. I'll try this out and let you know how it goes.

You can try to create the PDF file for the spreadsheet with the following function:
const pdfBlob = DriveApp.getFileById("ID OF THE SPREADSHEET FILE").getAs("application/pdf");
  
  const pdfName = `${name}_Certificate.pdf`;

Another approach that you can check is to make the export with the url and adding the PARAMETERS that you want to add:
//Retrieve the blob from the export URL.
  const id = spreadsheet.getId();
  const xlsxBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=${id}&exportFormat=pdf`, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}}).getBlob();


format=pdf: Set the exported file format to PDF
portrait=false: Sets the orientation to landscape (setting
portrait=true will result in portrait orientation)
gridlines=false: Do not show gridlines
size=b5: Set the page size to "B5"

You can check more information about the export for spreadsheet files here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/generate-pdfs
And here is another complete guide where you can check how to complete successfully the export to pdf: https://spreadsheet.dev/comprehensive-guide-export-google-sheets-to-pdf-excel-csv-apps-script
